# Sorting a linked list by finding the largest and placing it at the head

Tags: c, sorting, singly-linked-list, selection-sort, function-definition

Trying to figure out how to sort a linked list by finding the biggest integer deleting it and placing it at the head. So I wrote a function to find the biggest and place it at the head of the list. I tested it and it works. This is it.

```
NodePtr
getBiggest(NodePtr top)
{
    int big;
    NodePtr max, prev, before, head = top;

    big = head->num;

    while (head->next != NULL) {
        prev = head;
        head = head->next;
        if (big < head->num) {
            big = head->num;
            max = head;
            before = prev;
        }
    }

    before->next = max->next;
    max->next = top;
    top = max;

    return top;
}
```

I then wrote a function to sort the list. This one doesn't work as intended. I'm new to coding and I just need some inspiration. I'm trying but with no success.

```
NodePtr
sortList(NodePtr top)
{
    NodePtr getBiggest(NodePtr);
    NodePtr head = top, prev, rp, curr;

    rp = getBiggest(head);
    prev = rp;
    curr = rp->next;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        prev->next = getBiggest(curr);
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return rp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     curr = curr->next;
> ```

That's your problem.

Each time you find the next-biggest item, the unsorted portion of the list shrinks by one.  On the 1st iteration, you find the biggest item, and then search for the next biggest item.  But, instead of starting the 2nd search with item #2, you start with whatever the inserted node was pointing to as its next.

You want insertion to be the mirror of deletion.  Whenever you remove B from the chain A → B → C, you have to end up with A → C.  Likewise, when you insert B into A → C, you have to alter A → next to point to B, and B →*next* to point to A's old next: C.

In your code,

```
prev->next = getBiggest(curr);
```

`curr` is modified, and `prev->next` is destroyed.  Instead, change `getBiggest` to not modify its argument, and just return the biggest node from a starting point. Then,

```
while ((curr = getBiggest(curr->next)) != NULL) {
    NodePtr next = prev->next;
    prev->next = curr;
    curr->next = next;
}
```

I suggest writing *insert* and *delete* functions that take previous and current nodes as parameters.  That should help clear up what your loop should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getBiggest`

```
NodePtr getBiggest(NodePtr top){
int big;
NodePtr max,prev,before,head=top;
big=head->num;
while(head->next!=NULL){
prev=head;
head=head->next;
if(big<head->num){big=head->num;max=head;before=prev;}
}
before->next=max->next;
max->next=top;
top=max;
return top;
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because the pointer `before` is not initialized. So in the case when there are no nodes with the value greater than the value in the node pointed to by the pointer `top` when the pointer `before` will stay uninitialized.

Within the while loop of the function `sortList` there is used incorrectly the old value of the pointer `curr` in this statement

```
curr=curr->next;
```

Here is a demonstrative program with updated function definitions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct List
{
    int num;
    struct List *next; 
} *NodePtr;

NodePtr getBiggest( NodePtr head )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        NodePtr max  = head;
        NodePtr before_max = NULL;
        for ( NodePtr current = head->next, prev = head; 
              current != NULL; 
              prev = current, current = current->next )
        {
            if ( max->num < current->num )
            {
                max = current;;
                before_max = prev;
            }
        }
        
        if ( max != head )
        {
            before_max->next = max->next;
            max->next = head;
            head = max;
        }
    }
    
    return head;
}   

int push_front( NodePtr *head, int num )
{
    NodePtr new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->num  = num;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

FILE * display( NodePtr head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->num );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

NodePtr sortList( NodePtr head )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        head = getBiggest( head );
        
        NodePtr prev = head;
        
        while ( ( prev->next = getBiggest( prev->next ) ) != NULL ) 
        {
            prev = prev->next;
        }
    }
    
    return head;
}


int main(void) 
{
    NodePtr head = NULL;
    const int N = 10;
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( &head, rand() % N );
    }
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    head =  sortList( head );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
7 -> 3 -> 9 -> 1 -> 8 -> 0 -> 7 -> 0 -> 3 -> 5 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> null
```